# Work with dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css

```css
  .dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<li style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px" class="level1 nav-2-<?php echo $demmn; ?> first dropdown" >
          <a href="#" style="color:#fff">
             <span>TEST</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="background:#000;">
               <li style="width:50%"><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
               <li style="width:50%"><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
          </ul>
</li>
```

I want it show in horizontal like this

[image]

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```css
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.menu{
   max-width: 400px;
}

.menu>li{
  background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">

<li  style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px" class="level1 nav-2-<?php echo $demmn; ?> first dropdown" >
                  <a href="#" style="color:#fff">
                      <span>TEST</span>
                  </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="background:#111;">
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
  
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `li` items to have `display: inline-block` to make it horizontal.

If you want to control the width of each item, use `width` on the `li`.

If you want to limit how many items displayed per row, you can control it via `max-width` to make the row flow to the next line.

Adjust the `margin` on the `li` to have a little bit space between the items.

```html
    <li  style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px" class="level1 nav-2-<?php echo $demmn; ?> first dropdown" >
                  <a href="#" style="color:#fff">
                      <span>TEST</span>
                  </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="background:#000;">
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

    <style>
    .dropdown-menu {
      max-width: 390px;
    }
    .dropdown-menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
      width: 100px;
      min-height: 20px;
    }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try the flexbox, that permite you to make rows with efficient wrapped line

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /*make a row*/
  align-items: center; /*vertical align centered*/
  justify-content: space-between; /*horizontal align*/
}

.dropdown-menu li{
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*allow wrap line*/
  width: 33%; /*if u wnt 3 object per line*/
}
```

watch this website for more precision: 
[flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)